# How to search a string with special symbol in a line

Tags: python, regex

I have an "entity_set" which contains thousands of entities name, for example:

> ["CQ", "Pi", "+1", "M"]

and some lines contain one of the entities, for example,

> line1 = "What is M ?"
>
> line2 = "Who writes +1 ?"

I am using `re.search()` to match it, but I got an error when it matches with "+1":

> sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat at position 0

The reason is "+1" contains the special symbol "+".

Here is my code:

```py
for line in lines:
   for entity in entity_set:
       if re.search(r'{0}\s'.format(entity), line):
            STATEMENTS
```

How can I fix my code? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you are using literal text in regexp (i.e. text that should not get interpreted by the regexp engine), pass it through `re.escape` first:

```
re.search(r'{0}\s'.format(re.escape(entity)), line)
```

Comment: Thank you @Amadan . That is what I need.

Comment: When a "1" is an entity then its also catch the line "Who writes +1 ?". You have to add \s on the front of this expression.

Comment: @raze92 That actually depends on what one wants to do. If just one match is wanted, I'd probably sort the entities by descending length and break when I find one. If multiple non-overlapping ones are needed, I'd use `re.findall` with an alternation of all entities (again, sorted by descending length). But that wasn't the question. The question was "How to search a string with special symbol in a line".

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be:

```
entities = ["CQ", "Pi", "+1", "M"]
lines = ["What is M ?", "Who writes +1 ?"]
print([entity for entity in entities for line in lines if entity in line])
```

#### Output

```
['+1', 'M']
```

Comment: But in operation might match the substring. "1" and "+1" are all in my entity_list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
for line in lines:
   for entity in entity_set:
       if re.search(r'\s{0}\s'.format(re.escape(entity)), line):
            ...
```

Comment: But in operation might match the substring. "1" and "+1" are all in my entity_list.

Comment: I changed my answer, check this out!